# Which type of matrix has this property D F = F^{-T}

Tags: matrices

I was given a hint that

```
D det F = det F F^{-T}
```

where D is Frechet derivative that is total derivative.

by chain rule.
**Why does the following hold?** For which type of matrix?

```
D F = F^{-T}
```

Comment: Is $F^{-T}$ supposed to indicate the transpose of the inverse?

Comment: What is $D$?  We really need a lot more context to make sense of this.

Comment: D is Frechet derivative or total derivative. The context is Continuum Mechanics.

Comment: @CameronBuie I think it is so. I will verify it from my assistant too.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes. It means the transpose of the inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, the derivative of $\det F$ with respect to $F_{ij}$ is the cofactor $C_{ij}$.  The matrix of cofactors is $\det(F) (F^{-1})^T$.  See e.g.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29)

Comment: I do not see directly that derivative of $det F$ gives you the matrix of cofactors. I know that you get some derivate outside because of chain rule, but I am not sure that it is $(F^{-1})^{T}. Where the transpose come from?

Comment: Expand on row $i$: $\det F = \sum_k F_{ik} C_{ik}$.  The only term that depends on $F_{ij}$ is the one for $j=k$.
The $\det(F) (F^{-1})^T$ comes from Cramer's Rule.